# How to print out inputted ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, output, println

I'm trying to print out what I inputted for my ArrayList but I keep getting weird results such as this `[player@42a57993, player@75b84c92, player@6bc7c054]` when I clearly put in legitimate names. So take a look at my code and see what the problem might be:

```
if (o == 5) {
    double RD, t, old, x;
    String tournament, player;
    int a, number_of_players, place;
    ArrayList<player> players = new ArrayList<player>();
    System.out.println("1:Add a tournament \t2:View Existing");
    a = keyIn.nextInt();
        if (a == 1) {
            System.out.println("\nEnter tournament name");
            tournament = keyIn.next();
            System.out.println("\nEnter number of players");
            number_of_players = keyIn.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter players");
            for (int i = 0; i < number_of_players; i++) {
                String name = keyIn.next();
                player plr = new player();
                plr.setName(name);
                players.add(plr);
            }
            System.out.println("Enter places for");
            System.out.println(players);
            place = keyIn.nextInt();
```

Here is my `player` class:

```
public class player {

    private static String name;

    public void setName(String pName)
    {
        name = pName;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Let me know what you guys come up with! Thanks!

Comment: Remove the semicolon in that line `if (a == 1); {`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you see is the output of the default implementation of `toString`.
It's the class name followed by `@` and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the hash code.

To change that, implement a `toString` method in your `Player` class, for example:

```
public class Player {

    private String name;

    public void setName(String pName) {
        name = pName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Player{name='" + name + "'}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay so when I do this I'm getting what I'm looking for except now it's just taking my last input and repeating it for however many players there are supposed to be.

Comment: I don't think so. Notice that I changed your class a little bit: I made the `name` field non-static. In your original code, you used `static`, which means all object instances share that variable, that's why they are all the same. If you do like in my answer, it should work better.

Comment: Oh I didn't notice that! My mistake! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Java has no clue about local variable names after the item is added. When you run `Collections.toString`, it will simply call the `toString` method of all instances in the `ArrayList`.

You should override the `toString` method:

```
public class player {

    private static String name;

    public void setName(String pName) {
        name = pName;
    }

    public String getName() {

        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return name;
    }

}
```

The `toString` method specifies a textual representation of `Player` instances. The default `toString` method is printing the class of the instance as well as its location in memory.

There are of course alternative ways to produce a textual representation.

Comment: Okay so when I do this I'm getting what I'm looking for except now it's just taking my last input